# Flash AS3 won't allow the removal of a TextField or a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I added a movieclip here, and a number. To get an effect, like a star with a number.

The message is "starCount is not a child of a caller". I don't know what this means. It was added to the stage, so it should be there to be taken away.

```
var starClip = new ComboStarYellow();

starClip.x = 600;
starClip.y = 190;

if(ScoreKeep.comboTracker[starColor] == 0)
{
    starSprite.addChild(starClip);
}
else
{

    if(starClip!= null && starClip.parent != null)
    {
        removeChild(starClip);
    }

    if(starCount!= null && starCount.parent != null)
    {
        removeChild(starCount);
    }


    var starCount:TextField = new TextField();
    var starFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    starFormat.font="SF Atarian System Extended";
    starFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;
    starFormat.size = 20;


    starCount.text = ScoreKeep.comboTracker[starColor].toString();
    starCount.x = 600;
    starCount.y = 200;
    starCount.setTextFormat(starFormat);
    starSprite.addChild(starClip);
    starSprite.addChild(starCount);
}
```

Comment: "Flash always amazes me with its new ruptures in logic and basic intuition" you mean you amaze yourself cos Flash just does what the coder ask it to do so if something goes wrong please blame the true responsible: you. Your obviously upset and good for you if you manage to take it on anything else other than your lack of skills.

Comment: Please refrain from using profanities and angry text etc. See here  http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 4):

It's sadly an error on your end not ActionScript's. This line is incorrect:

```
removeChild(starClip);
```

You added starClip to starSprite not the stage hence the error. You need to remove starClip from starSprite.

```
starSprite.removeChild(starClip);
```

In fact you may have a few issues in your code to do with scoping.